# lsusb is not working on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, lsusb

I have an Ubuntu server version (14.04 up to date LTS). I mostly use this machine over SSH.

Yesterday I typed in `lsusb` and the machine gave me the following error:

> `unable to initialize libusb: -99`

I searched on the web, but did not get any answers on this problem.

Question: What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

*Note: The machine is installed on an ESXI machine and the usb devices are passed through ESXI.*

Comment: Probably this server does not have usb. What do you want to get from that command?

Comment: It is running in an ESXI server enviroment could that be the problem? Well, what lsusb does list the inserted usb drives.

Comment: So it has no direct access to usb

Comment: I added the usb via ESXI so it could be possible, right? But, yes Ubuntu is not installed on the bare metal and has unlimited access to the USB ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unable to initialize libusb` could be because there is no USB controllers present on the Server. You can check it out by executing the following command:

```
lspci | grep USB
```

In your case, there would be no output, indicating the absence of USB controllers. If so, then add one. I have not worked much on VMs, so I can't tell anything about that, but upon googling, I found several pages that might help you, including [this](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/configuring_virtual_machines/t_add_a_usb_device_to_esx_exsi_host.html) .

Comment: Of course adding an USB controller!! Thanks mate